# Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat CameraView produces Android No view found for fragment CameraFragment error

Tags: xamarin.android, .net-maui

Thanks in advance!! I'm quite new to XAML so be kind :)
My requirement is to add a CameraView to a .net Maui app which runs on Android and iOS.
I understand that there is no CameraView in the Maui.Community.Toolkit but I was under the impression, which may be wrong, that I could run the Xamarin.Community.Tookit.MauiCompat packages which I'm trying to do in the code below.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Hosting;
etc...

namespace Mobile;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
        });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();        
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, AuthStateProvider>();
        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

        builder.UseMauiCompatibility();
        builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
        {
            // Register ALL handlers in the Xamarin Community Toolkit assembly
            handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderers(typeof(Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.CameraViewRenderer).Assembly);

            // Register just one handler for the control you need
            handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.CameraView), typeof(Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.CameraViewRenderer));
        });

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml (Which I simply pasted from https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/CameraViewPage.xaml.cs)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui;assembly=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile"
         xmlns:data="clr-namespace:Mobile.Data"
         xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;assembly=ZXing.Net.MAUI"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         x:Class="Mobile.MainPage"
         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <data:ShowQrReaderConverter x:Key="ShowQrReaderConverter"/>
    <data:ShowFrCapturingConverter x:Key="ShowFrCapturingConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<AbsoluteLayout>
    <b:BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html" 
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" 
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <b:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <b:RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
        </b:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </b:BlazorWebView>

    <!-- QR Reader -->
    Removed for brevity...

    <!-- FR Camera View -->
    <AbsoluteLayout
        x:Name="absLayout2"
        Margin="0,334"
        BackgroundColor="Beige"
        HeightRequest="{Binding availableQrReaderHeight}"
        WidthRequest="{Binding availableQrReaderWidth}"
        >
        <AbsoluteLayout.TranslationX>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ShowFrCapturingConverter}">
                <Binding Path="CardToggle" />
                <Binding Path="cameraViewerCapturing" />
                <Binding Path="AppState.ShootMode" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </AbsoluteLayout.TranslationX>

        <Grid RowDefinitions="300, Auto, *">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, *" Grid.Row="0">
            <xct:CameraView
                Grid.Column="0"
                x:Name="cameraView"
                CaptureMode="Photo"
                FlashMode="Off"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                MediaCaptured="CameraView_MediaCaptured"
                OnAvailable="CameraView_OnAvailable"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Camera"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="End" />

            <Image
                Grid.Column="1"
                x:Name="previewPicture"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                BackgroundColor="LightGray" />

            <xct:MediaElement
                Grid.Column="1"
                x:Name="previewVideo"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                IsVisible="false"/>
            <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="Result"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="End" />
        </Grid>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label x:Name="zoomLabel" />
            <Slider
                x:Name="zoomSlider"
                Margin="5,0"
                IsEnabled="False"
                Maximum="10"
                Minimum="1"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ValueChanged="ZoomSlider_ValueChanged"
                Value="1" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, *" RowDefinitions="*,*">
                <StackLayout
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="5"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Switch
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"
                        IsToggled="False"
                        Toggled="VideoSwitch_Toggled" />
                    <Label Text="Video" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="5"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Switch
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"
                        IsToggled="False"
                        Toggled="FrontCameraSwitch_Toggled" />
                    <Label Text="Front camera" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="5"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Switch
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"
                        IsToggled="False"
                        Toggled="FlashSwitch_Toggled" />
                    <Label Text="Flash" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>

            <Button
                x:Name="doCameraThings"
                Clicked="DoCameraThings_Clicked"
                IsEnabled="False"
                Text="Snap picture" />
            
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
...
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;

namespace Mobile;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
LocalDb _db;
AppStateService _AppStateService;
CommonMethods _CommonMethods;

public MainPage(AppStateService AppStateService, LocalDb db, CommonMethods CommonMethods)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = AppStateService;

    _AppStateService = AppStateService;
    _db = db;
    _CommonMethods = CommonMethods;

    zoomLabel.Text = string.Format("Zoom: {0}", zoomSlider.Value);
}

//Begin CameraView methods
void ZoomSlider_ValueChanged(object? sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    cameraView.Zoom = (float)zoomSlider.Value;
    zoomLabel.Text = string.Format("Zoom: {0}", Math.Round(zoomSlider.Value));
}

void VideoSwitch_Toggled(object? sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    var captureVideo = e.Value;

    if (captureVideo)
        cameraView.CaptureMode = CameraCaptureMode.Video;
    else
        cameraView.CaptureMode = CameraCaptureMode.Photo;

    previewPicture.IsVisible = !captureVideo;

    doCameraThings.Text = e.Value ? "Start Recording"
        : "Snap Picture";
}

// You can also set it to Default and External
void FrontCameraSwitch_Toggled(object? sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    => cameraView.CameraOptions = e.Value ? CameraOptions.Front : CameraOptions.Back;

// You can also set it to Torch (always on) and Auto
void FlashSwitch_Toggled(object? sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    => cameraView.FlashMode = e.Value ? CameraFlashMode.On : CameraFlashMode.Off;

void DoCameraThings_Clicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cameraView.Shutter();
    doCameraThings.Text = cameraView.CaptureMode == CameraCaptureMode.Video
        ? "Stop Recording"
        : "Snap Picture";
}

void CameraView_OnAvailable(object? sender, bool e)
{
    if (e)
    {
        zoomSlider.Value = cameraView.Zoom;
        var max = cameraView.MaxZoom;
        if (max > zoomSlider.Minimum && max > zoomSlider.Value)
            zoomSlider.Maximum = max;
        else
            zoomSlider.Maximum = zoomSlider.Minimum + 1; // if max == min throws exception
    }

    doCameraThings.IsEnabled = e;
    zoomSlider.IsEnabled = e;
}

void CameraView_MediaCaptured(object? sender, MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (cameraView.CaptureMode)
    {
        default:
        case CameraCaptureMode.Default:
        case CameraCaptureMode.Photo:
            previewVideo.IsVisible = false;
            previewPicture.IsVisible = true;
            previewPicture.Rotation = e.Rotation;
            previewPicture.Source = e.Image;
            doCameraThings.Text = "Snap Picture";
            break;
        case CameraCaptureMode.Video:
            previewPicture.IsVisible = false;
            previewVideo.IsVisible = true;
            previewVideo.Source = e.Video;
            doCameraThings.Text = "Start Recording";
            break;
    }
}
```

}

This produces the error:

> No view found for id 0x1 (unknown) for fragment CameraFragment{f98267d} (57bc3319-7a90-475b-a4d0-458320859acb id=0x1 tag=camera)

Comment: The content on this website may be helpful to you:"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003780/no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment-in-custom-dialogfragment/24128317".